# React with TypeScript, prompt() return value

Tags: reactjs, typescript

TypesScript shows an error when I want to update my `State`

TyepScript underlines in red the `prompValue` in `setapiKey(prompValue);` inside the `getApiKey` function, and the error is:

> Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction'.
> Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction'.ts(2345)

What is the problem how can I fix this?

```
function App() {

  const [apiKey, setapiKey] = useState('');

  const getApiKey = () => {
    const prompValue = prompt('Enter API Key');
    setapiKey(prompValue);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>App</h1>
      <button onClick={getApiKey}>API</button>
      <p>{apiKey}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, it's the powerful of typescript. `prompt` returns `string` | `null`.

You should handle the situation when the user cancels the prompt dialog to reduce mistakes.

```js
function App() {

  const [apiKey, setapiKey] = useState('');

  const getApiKey = () => {
    const prompValue = prompt('Enter API Key');
    if(prompValue === null) {
      // do what ever you want when the user cancel the prompt
    }
    else {
      setapiKey(prompValue);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>App</h1>
      <button onClick={getApiKey}>API</button>
      <p>{apiKey}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: nice and breif explanation.

Comment: Thank You!!!
I've got 5 days to make a project in TypeScript-React, and this is the first time I'm using TypeScript... (I guess a lot of questions will coming from me... :) )

Comment: It's a good choice. TS will gain your experience so much with a bit stuck. 

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the answers, the `prompt` return `string` (in case of user tried to write something) and `null` in case of user close the prompt without type anything on it.

So, Typescript will care about the `promptValue`. it assumes the type of your value is one of the `string` or `null`.

since the `promptValue` is a string there is no problem because you defined your `apiKey` value as a string which initialized in `useState` with an empty string.

But in the case of returning null from `promptValue`, typescript prevents you to put the `null` value into the `apiKey` which is defined as a string.